# Detect and replace region from one image onto another image with OpenCV

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have two pictures of the same dimension and I want to detect and replace the white region in the first picture (black image) at the same location in the second picture. Is there any way to do this using `OpenCV`? I want to replace the blue region in the original image with the white region in the first picture.

First picture

[image]

Original image

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to replace the white ROI on the black image onto the original image. Here's a simple approach:

1. **Obtain binary image.** Load image, grayscale, [Gaussian blur](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_filtering/py_filtering.html#gaussian-filtering), then [Otsu's threshold](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html#otsus-binarization)
2. **Extract ROI and replace.** Find contours with [`cv2.findContours`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours) then filter using contour approximation with [`cv2.arcLength`](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contour_features/py_contour_features.html#contour-perimeter) and [`cv2.approxPolyDP`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#approxpolydp). With the assumption that the region is a rectangle, if the contour approximation result is `4` then we have found our desired region. In addition, we filter using [`cv2.contourArea`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#contourarea) to ensure that we don't include noise. Finally we obtain the bounding box coordinates with [`cv2.boundingRect`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=boundingrect#boundingrect) and extract the ROI with Numpy slicing. Finally we replace the ROI into the original image.

---

Detected region to extract/replace highlighted in green

[image]

Extracted ROI

[image]

Result

[image]

Code

```
import cv2

# Load images, grayscale, Gaussian blur, Otsu's threshold
original = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
image = cv2.imread('2.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3,3), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Find contours, filter using contour approximation + area, then extract
# ROI using Numpy slicing and replace into original image
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.015 * peri, True)
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if len(approx) == 4 and area > 1000:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        ROI = image[y:y+h,x:x+w]
        original[y:y+h, x:x+w] = ROI

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('ROI', ROI)
cv2.imshow('original', original)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your help!

Comment: I’m looking to do something similar, except I am replacing a circular logo with another circular logo in multiple images. Is the code the same if the region is round instead of a rectangle?

Comment: No you would have to adjust the contour approximation value, in this specific example its `4` because that's for rectangle or circle. If you want to find a circular logo change it to like 9+ or something